# Photo Delete from PC but not from iphone

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos

What if I want to upload 10 photos to iPhone from PC, without using the internet. I don't want to keep the photos on the PC and want to maintain only one copy at the mobile. How do I do that?

1) Since it's not mac I don't think I can use the airdrop 
2) Syncing via iTunes will remove pics from mobile as soon as I clear them from PC, so what's the solution??

Is there any way to **"unsync"** the photos I have synced via iTunes. Since there are 10-20 photos from different dates, making a duplicate is too tedious, that too, when I have to go in Photos collection and search for them.

Comment: In Addition to above question, can anyone suggest me how to transfer one picture at a time from PC to iphone without internet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an iCloud account and have My Photo Stream enabled they should sync right to your iCloud.

Comment: Doesn't that require internet, I'm trying to figure out if USB is of any use for such matter, any "offline" suggestion?